# Failed to connect using ipv6 outside rootless container

Tags: docker, ipv6, rootless

I'am trying to setup my services with `rootless docker` using default `rootlesskit` with `slirp4netns`. Everything works file until my service try to connect using ipv6 to outside service. With `curl -6 [<some exising ipv6 address>]:8080` I always have `Network is unreachable`, in same time connections to same server with ipv4 works fine.
I've enabled ipv6 in docker:

```
{
  "ipv6": true,
  "fixed-cidr-v6": "2001:db8:1::/64",
  "experimental": true,
  "ip6tables": true
}
```

and enabled ipv6 in rootlesskit with flag `--ipv6`. What I'm doing wrong? Does rootlesskit with slirp4netns support outside connections via ipv6?

Thanks a lot. Hope someone here can help me after a week of reading manuals...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slirp4netns does not support IPv6. You can track the progress of that with this issue: https://github.com/rootless-containers/slirp4netns/issues/253